# 'rospack' tries to load libboost_filesystem.so.1.46.1 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have Ubuntu 14.04, and installed ROS Indigo using the steps documented [here](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu), but auto-completion using  for `$ roscd <package_name>` gives the following error:

`rospack: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_filesystem.so.1.46.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

`rosstack: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_filesystem.so.1.46.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

So, I purged everything (boost and ROS) and re-installed ROS, with the exactly same results as above

- Installed Boost version: 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1  (via dpkg)
- Installed rospack version:  2.2.5-0trusty-20140904-1937-+0000 (via dpkg)

Any ideas why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193090/%27rospack%27-tries-to-load-libboost_filesystem.so.1.46.1-in-ubuntu-14.04/) by [kunaltyagi](https://answers.ros.org/users/18850/kunaltyagi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2014-09-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-09-19**:
Can you check which version of rospack you are calling (`which rospack`)? And which version of rospack and boost you have installed (`dpkg -l | grep rospack`, `dpkg -l | grep boost`)?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-09-19**:
`which rospack`?

**Comment by [kunaltyagi](https://answers.ros.org/users/18850/kunaltyagi/) on 2014-09-19**:
/opt/ros/indigo/bin/rospack

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-09-20**:
Please run `ldd /opt/ros/indigo/bin/rospack` and post the line listing the boost filesystem library. Please run `ll /PATH/TO/libboost_filesystem.so.VERSION` to double check that it is not a symlink to an older version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all those who might face the problem.
I resolved the problem by:

- removing the /opt/ros directory, uninstalling ros-indigo-desktop-full and re-installing it.

Now everything's peachy.

---

Originally posted by [kunaltyagi](https://answers.ros.org/users/18850/kunaltyagi/) with karma: 105 on 2014-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0